# How to explicitly declare the type of a member var in a php class

Tags: php

If I can explicitly declare the type of a member var (esp. other class as a member), them my IDE( such as Dreamweaver) can know the member's member.

```
class PHPClass(){
    OtherClass $member_var;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only way is to use documentation like so:

```
class MyClass {

    /**
     * @var OtherClass This is my other class
     */
    private $other;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that in PHP but you can come close by using [type hinting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

```
class PHPClass
{
    protected $member_var;

    public function __construct(OtherClass $member)
    {
        $this->member_var = $member;
    }
}
```

I don't know if that will help you in Dreamweaver, though.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7.4, property definitions can have type declarations.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties.typed-properties

Comment: This would be even better with a small code example, in case the link is inaccessible (you never know where sites can be blocked).